# Native app - entering amount

Tags: mobile, payment

Currently we have two different ways to enter amount into amount field.

1. Example 1 - formatting is done automatically. User always needs to enter decimals even if they want to pay only 1 EUR.
2. Example 2 - Users needs to format amount manually using comma/period which can be frustrating on mobile devices.

We have done some user testings and we have very tied results. Any suggestion which type of amount entering should be used in our native applications (banking apps)

Mock
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If built correctly, any numerical input field should trigger a numerical keypad on mobile devices - this generally includes a decimal marker reducing the amount of hunting or keyboard switching the user needs to do.

With that in mind, I would suggest that you follow the second method but with the following change: any missing decimal places can be added by the software - thus if the user enters "12", the software understands it as " 12.00". If they enter "12.5", the software understands it as " 12.50", etc. This would mean that the user can enter the value in a way that is comfortable for them.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer option 2 because you have to type less than in 1, and because most of the calculators and numeric input boxes work in that way (technically talking, it is about mental models and affordances governing our interaction).

If you type an integer like 15 you might get a 0.15, and that is not what you expected.